# Excel Macro VBA commands for "transpose" but no transpose available

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to change a set of data that has headers. Currently the expected columns are all in seperate rows. I want to keep the 1st data point, "name", in Column A, but move the 2nd data point, "number" to Column B, and 3rd data point, "average" to Column C. Then delete those now empty two lines where number and average existed and repeat this process for the next set of data. Example:

- Name, Number, Average (expected headers)
- Josh
- 13
- 3.4
- Craig
- 15
- 2.3
- Smith
- 64
- 8.3

Here is what I'd like it to be:

- Name, Number, Average (expected headers)
- Josh, 13, 3.4
- Craig, 15, 2.3
- Smith, 64, 8.3

I've tried a few things:

1) Transpose... however for some reason this PasteSpecial function is not available in the .XLSM file I'm embedding this to. Code reference:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

2) Copy and Paste. This is a work in progress and the code does not compile.

```
For k = 3 To maxRow Step 1
    Rows(k).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range(Columns("B"), Rows(k)).Select
    Selection.Paste
    Rows(k + 1).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range(Rows(k), Columns(C)).Paste
    'Range(Columns("B"), Rows(k)).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    'Range(Rows(k), Rows(k + 2)).Select
    'Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Next k
```

I have at least a thousand data points. My code is able to process to the last line however this is the last critical function in my macro. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
For k = 3 To maxRow Step 3
  Sheet2.Cells(Int((k + 1) / 3), 1).Resize(, 3).Value = _
    Application.Transpose(Sheet1.Cells(k, 1).Resize(3).Value)
Next k
```

Comment: Wonderful that works well in addressing the transpose issue. I will use that in the future. I did find a solution as it was mostly incorrectly using the Range command.
{
    Dim maxRow3 As Long
    maxRow3 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For k = 3 To maxRow Step 1
        Cells(k, 1).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Cells(k - 1, 2).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Cells(k + 1, 1).Select
        Selection.Cut
        Cells(k - 1, 3).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range(Rows(k), Rows(k + 1)).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=x1Up
    Next k
}

Comment: @jfadriqu sorry I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: No worries, your suggestion works well. I just ended up with a longer, manual for loop to do this which is what I wrote there.